# Need to download latest war file using get_url in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, artifactory

Need to download latest war file from Artifactory using get_url method in ansible.

```
- name: Download war file from artifactory
 get_url:
   url: http://localhost:5040/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/libs-snapshot-local/devops/ilp1/ILP/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ILP-0.0.1-20200408.072920-1.war
   dest: /home/osgdev/devops_capstone/testnew/ILP_BookStoreWorkspace/roles/ansi
```

Below the code which i have tried.

```
 name: Download war file from artifactory
 get_url:
   url: http://localhost:5040/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/devops/ilp1/ILP/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/latest.war
   dest: /home/osgdev/devops_capstone/testnew/ILP_BookStoreWorkspace/roles/ansicode here
```

Getting the below message:
TASK [ansi : Download war file from artifactory] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named lxml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_NrEV35/ansible_module_maven_artifact.py\", line 158, in \n    from lxml import etree\nImportError: No module named lxml\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/osgdev/devops_capstone/testnew/ILP_BookStoreWorkspace/roles/ansi/ansi.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

I have 2 or more files is there, but i need to download the latest war file

ILP-0.0.1-20200408.072920-1.war
ILP-0.0.1-20200410.071653-2.war

Please help on this.

Comment: You have failed to specify what you have already tried, and what error message it is producing for you. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Comment: Below the code i have tried

Answer (score 0):

The Artifactory [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact) supports downloading the latest Maven version for both releases and snapshots.
For snapshots you should use the following format in the Ansible url field:

```
http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ivy-local/org/acme/1.0-[SNAPSHOT]/acme-1.0-[SNAPSHOT].jar
```

For releases you should use the following format:

```
http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ivy-local/org/acme/[RELEASE]/acme-[RELEASE].jar
```